# Possible solution for changing information displayed in test results screen in Azure DevOps

Tags: c#, selenium, azure-devops, automated-tests, nunit

I am working on a automation testing project with Selenium Webdriver and I have deployed it on Azure DevOps. After I run the test I can the test result window. There is a column named TimeStamp which is displayed in the results window. It displays the the day as either yesterday or Monday/Tuesday(day of week). Is there a way to show the date and time in the same column or in a separate column in a format like 9/20/2022 1:00 PM EST. Look forward to get a solution for this.

[image]

Comment: Can't you view the logs as the build or release pipeline is running?

Comment: I guess I'm not clear what your question is.

Comment: If you hover your mouse cursor over "Yesterday" or one of the days of the week, do you get a tooltip with the date/time?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.